# boxing ring feet

Tags: foley

Need to foley some feet on a boxing ring in the studio in the next couple of weeks, anyone done this before? boxing rings have a very specific sound, dont think i'll have time to go to the local boxing gym and record a wildtrack (busy schedule), anyone got any ideas on how to build my own canvas in the studio? or something that sounds right! much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want I might have some stuff, it's just general background practising ambience recorded at a boxing gym in London.

Comment: Its the feet that I need specifically, the canvas feet, scuffs etc. Its for a fight scene thats set in olden times, so its a tricky one...

Comment: What I have might do, it's feet, hollow canvas noise, etc. If layered in with crowd noise it may well work, indeed I recorded it for a scene very similar to the one you've described. Drop me a mail - paulw@earcom.net.